# Count images in some folder on WEB server (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

I need to count and check how much of some images is placed in folder od web server.
Example- images get names from `user_id`, and on example I have `user_id 27`, and my images are:

```
27_1.jpg, 27_2.jpg, 27_3.jpg, ...
```

How to check and write to database this thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Once you know your path you can use IO.Directory.GetFiles() method.

```
IO.Directory.GetFiles("\translated\path","27_*.jpg").Count()
```

will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the System.IO namespace, you can do something like this

```
public File[] GetUserFiles(int userId)
{
   List<File> files = new List<File>();

   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\folderyoulookingfor");
   foreach(File f in di.GetFiles())
   {
      if(f.ToString().StartsWith(userId.ToString()))
         files.Add(f);
   }
   return file.ToArray();
}
```